# How to upload video directly to AWS S3 Version 2 ? Sample app are not useful enough

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload video to the S3 server with temporary credential access. Its ~3Mb file. I tried with AWS S3 Sample examples . I don't want to use AWS Cognito. So now how to upload the video .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to write some code to use Presigned PUT object - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample code to upload text file on amazon

```
- (void)upload
{
    AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    // *** Set background task accordingly ***
    [appDel setApplicationObj:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
    [appDel setBgTask:[[appDel applicationObj] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[appDel applicationObj] endBackgroundTask:[APP_DEL bgTask]];
        [appDel setBgTask:UIBackgroundTaskInvalid];
    }]];

    // *** Begin file upload task to Amazon ***
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        // File upload task .
        @try {
            // *** Initialize AmazonS3Client object using AccessKey and SecretKey ***
            AmazonS3Client *objAmazonS3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"<Access Key>" withSecretKey:@"<Secret Key>"];
            objAmazonS3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_EAST_1];

            // *** Initialize S3PutObjectRequest with filename & bucket in which to drop it. ***
            S3PutObjectRequest *objS3PutRequest = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"MyFile.txt" inBucket:@"<Bucket Name>"];
            // *** Set content type according to your file type, here its plain text ****
            [objS3PutRequest setContentType:@"text/plain"];
            // *** set NSData of your File, here i am converting String into NSData ***
            NSData *data = [@"This is my sample text" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [objS3PutRequest setData:data];
            // *** Its optional ***
            [objS3PutRequest setRequestTag:@"fileUpload"];

            // *** Start upload task by putting request ***
            [objAmazonS3 putObject:objS3PutRequest];

            // *** Register upload callback, when it finishes upload it will invoke following method ***
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fileUploadCallback)
                                   withObject:nil
                                waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
        @catch (AmazonClientException *exception)
        {
            NSLog(@"File Upload Failed, Reason: %@", exception);
        }
    });
}

- (void)fileUploadCallback
{
    NSLog(@"Upload complete.");
}
```